# My array is not reaching the last element of my array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public int numProjectsGraded(String fname, String lname) {
     
      if(fName == null || lName == null || 
             )
          
          return -1;
      
      String name = fName + " " + lName;
     
      for(int i = 0; i < tList.length-1; i++ ) {
       
          if(tList[i].tName().compareTo(name) == 0) {
              
              return tList[i].getProjects(); 
          }
   }
      return -1;
  }
```

The array is not reaching the last element for some reason. What’s wrong with it?

Comment: you are looping til length -1 with strict less than

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < taList.length-1; i++ )` think what it means stopping *before* (as implied by `<`) reaching `length - 1`

Comment: As an aside, `firstName.isEmpty() == true` is redundant and (when using variables instead of method calls) error prone (you may write `=` instead of `==` by mistake, it would compile and you would spend ridiculous amounts of time looking for a hard to see bug). The idiomatic way is simply using `firstName.isEmpty()` itself as a condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < taList.length-1; i++ )
```

means if `i` is equal to `taList.length-1`, don't enter to the block.

Hence, consider changing it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < taList.length; i++ )
```

Comment: oh you're totally right thanks for the help. I knew there was a simple solution to this

Answer (score 0):

The iteration final condition should be `i < taList.length` instead of `i < taList.length -1`